# tf and amcl turtlebot demo immediately after gmap demo

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, gmapping, amcl, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the turtlebot I am trying to launch the amcl demo after launching the gmapping demo, but without shutting down all of ros.

Usually I can get the gmapping to work (that's the first demo I test) and then the amcl will partially work. I can load a map using 'map_store' and then see the map on the rviz screen. I also can usually see the turtlebot on the rviz screen. I have trouble directing the turtlebot, though, and I don't exactly know why.

When I look at the RobotModel listing under the 'Displays' box in rviz it's red, and the cause is that the tf's from all the components are red. (base_footprint, base_link, etc., all red).  They all say 'No transform from [base_footprint] to [map]'. When I execute view_frames and look at the pdf it says "no tf data received". When I type rostopic list '/tf' comes up as one of my topics. Is there something I can start that will restart the tf data in the turtlebot?

If I don't start gmapping first I can usually load a map and direct the turtlebot with /initialpose, etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134091/tf-and-amcl-turtlebot-demo-immediately-after-gmap-demo/) by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using multiple terminals: start the basic turtlebot nodes, i.e. `turtlebot_bringup/minimal.launch` in the first terminal and the app, e.g. make a map, in a second demo. Then, when you like to launch a different set of nodes/app, only kill the launcher in the second terminal and execute the new launcher.

If you have further nodes, which manage data and need to remain active, e.g. *map_store*, use more terminals and make sure to exclude those nodes from your app launcher.

Hope this helps!

PS: You might want to take a look at the [rocon_app_manager package](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_app_manager). The app manager handles the starting and stopping of rapps (robot apps). We use it frequently on our turtlebots for creating and navigating a map as well as teleop.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2014-03-30**:
If your problem has been solved, please select the best answer thereby marking your question as answered.